# How to update item and user factors ALS in Group Specific Recommendation?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I was going through this Group Specific Recommendation System [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307616210_A_Group-Specific_Recommender_System). I want to implement this from scratch. I see that they have used Alternating Least Square. But how are they updating the item factors and user factors? Do I need to find the gradient of those equations (5), (6), (7), (8)?

The algorithm I am talking about is in 3.2.

Someone help me visualize this via an example of how is the calculation happening. Let me give a short example.

$Users \times Items$ matrix-

```
[[4, 5, NaN],
 [1, NaN, 2],
 [NaN, 1, 3]]
```

User latent factors ($U = Users \times K$). In the mentioned paper it is $P$.
$K = latent\ factor\ dimension = 2$

```
[[0.5,  1],
 [-2,   3],
 [-1.5, 4]]
```

Item latent factors ($M^T = K \times Items$). In the mentioned paper it is $Q$.
$K = latent\ factor\ dimension = 2$

```
[[0.5,  2, -3],
 [1.5,  3, -2]]
```

$S$

```
[[1,   -1],
 [-4, 0.4],
 [-5.5, 4]]
```

$T$

```
[[0.5,  1,    -1],
 [-1,   0.5, 2.5]]
```

How is the calculation with this dummy example?

Comment: Cross posted on [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/35527/17742).

Comment: Have you tried using the implicit package in python? https://benfred.github.io/implicit/tutorial_lastfm.html#Training-a-Model . This uses ALS